# Create document highlights the extension in 22.04. In 20.04 only the name was highlighted, not the extension

Tags: xubuntu

When I right-click in a directory (xfce) in Xubuntu 22.04 to create a document, the entire file name and extension are highlighted. In 20.04, only the name is highlighted and not the extension. How can I set up this behavior in 22.04?